# Language Translation API C#

Tags: c#, google-translate

I am attempting to create a natural language processing program in which I must be able to translate words and sentences as well as getting their parts of speech. I have heard that you can implement Google Translate API in your program, but have worked on it with no luck for the past 2 weeks. I have tried looking at other translation services such as [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5768/Translation-Web-Service-in-C), but with my very limited background in C#, I can not make much out of the article. Can anybody provide me with a simple walk through, I would like to learn what I am doing so I can further my knowledge of C#, that I can use to be able to accomplish my goal. It does not have to be the Google API, but any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered Microsoft Translator? It integrates with C# pretty easily. See http://www.microsofttranslator.com/dev/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two mainstream options are

1. the [Microsoft API](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/1899a118-d202-492c-aa16-ba21c33c06cb), this is free to a certain limit
2. the [Google API](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing) is a paid service

An cheap and dirty option would be to call the Google translate directly via a HTTP request (in another words screen scrape the Google translate page) with the new ASP.NET Web API its quite easy to do HTTP requests elegantly.  eg: to translate the English phrase "test this" from English to French you need the below URL.

http://translate.google.com/#en/fr/test%20this

Here is the [asp.net web api resource](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use the code from the article in the way you intend. Since it's writing Bing took over altavista and changed what the destination of the url is, and this code didn't do any translation itself anyway, it just passes it off to babelfish to chew on but not in a way that is stable long term.

I'd go with google translate https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started

Best of luck!